# Why are some computers are slow during file copy process?

Tags: hard-drive, benchmarking, io

I have a modern laptop (quad-core i5 2.5GHz, 4GB RAM, ) at work. But it is very slow and unresponsive when I copy files in the background.On the other side, at home I have a simple 2-core PC (E2180 2 GHz CPU, 2GB RAM) and I do not observe any reduction of the performance whenever I copy anything. Both computers have similar HDDs installed and both tested using same file systems, operating systems and drivers. So, I am trying to understand what can cause such performance drop. Is it a typical problem of all laptops? According to PassMark chart table my PC should be 2-times slower than my laptop, but it's not the case: my PC is much faster under high I/O load. Do you know any reliable performance chart which takes into account this kind of tasks (file copy, I/O)?

Comment: Same anti-malware apps in use too?

Comment: Is one computer set to ancient IDE compatibility mode and one to AHCI (AHCI performs better under load).

Comment: Laptops tend to have 5400 RPM 2.5" hard drives whereas PCs usually have 3.5" which are usually 7200 RPM.  The speed of both has risen considerably in recent years but it could still be a factor.  Is there a lot of hard drive activity on your laptop when you're NOT copying files?  CPU is usually not a factor when copying files but RAM can be -- if it's maxed out it will force a lot of disk swapping.

Answer (score 2):

Virus scanners in companies are notoriously slow. That's probably because the persons affected (employees) are not the persons who choose the virus scanner.

The person who chooses the virus scanner will not be fired for wasting 1 hour/employee/day, but might be fired if a virus gets through. So his best strategy is to make it look like he did everything possible, including cranking up the scanner settings to Ludicrous.